# Getting subnet mask of specific devices

Tags: bash

I'm trying to only print the line "netmask 255.255.255.0" using ifconfig with awk command on RHEL but failed to do so. The closet I can get is using the following

```
ifconfig enp0s3 | awk 'NR==2{print $3}
```

Which will print only "netmask"

I'm trying to achieve printing "Netmask: 255.255.255.0", which i also need to add the ':' inbetween, is it possible?

[image]

Comment: post the output of `ifconfig` command.

Comment: you mean this `ifconfig enp0s3 | awk 'NR==2{print $3":"$4}'`

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate third and fourth column with `:`

```
ifconfig enp0s3 | awk 'NR==2{print $3":"$4}'
```